# How to change created time stamp one week ago?

Tags: touch

I want to change the created timestamp of many images one week ago. 
Code

```
% http://askubuntu.com/a/62496/25388
touch -d "7 days ago" *.png
```

Output

```
touch: invalid date format ‘1 one ago’
```

OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `- foo` format:

```
$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Nov 29 11:05 file
$ touch -d '-1 week' file 
$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Nov 22 11:06 file
```